# Class diagram usage in UML

Tags: abstract-class, implementation, uml, class-diagram

As I read through

" Unified Modeling Language User Guide,
Grady Booch ,James Rumbaugh ,Ivar Jacobson 
Publisher: Addison Wesley 
First Edition October 20, 1998 "

that :

> You use classes to capture the vocabulary of the system you are
>   developing. These **classes may include abstractions that are part of
>   the problem domain**, as well as **classes that make up an implementation**

Could you please clarify the quoted sentences through simple example in UML and please focus on two bold sentences ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You use classes to capture the vocabulary of the system you are
>   developing.

This means you should turn the concepts you found in your requirements understanding into your "domain entities" and let them be represented into the class diagram.

> These classes may include abstractions that are part of
>   the problem domain,

[image]

https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoONs8CzYit0VXZ9H7Au9MXgE8Fx0a2hsSOs8Kt3BLVWw_Il6U

BankAccount is a high level abstraction. CheckAccount and SavingsAccount are lower level abstractions.

> as well as classes that make up an implementation

[image]

http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/code/gameoflife-uml.png

In this other example you see an implementation diagram, which already involves technology with your design and implementation decisions.

Comment: thank you @gustavogbc that's very kind of you.Could you please add a short description for each class related to the game of life(second figure)?

Comment: please follow the link on the images. they are just references i've used to explain you. and if it was an answer for you, please confirm and upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Class diagrams can be used  for Domain Model: Conceptual Classes**

In Object Oriented analysis, we can create **domain models**

> A domain model is the visual representation of real situation objects
>   in the domain-problem space.

*Why Create Domain Model?*

To understand key concepts and the vocabulary of domain-problem space.

And

*While we are developing software classes ,Domain classes give us inspiration.*

For example here is a partial domain model for a Monopoly Game.

[image]

In this diagram "Die" is a real world "Die". And our aim is to understand "Monopoly" game.

**Class diagramas can be used for Implementation : Software Classes**

They are classes which we (will) implement in a programming language.They represent software abstractions. They are inspired from domain model but there is no one to one mapping between them.

Here is a sample partial simple Software Class diagram for Monopoly Game

[image]

**Even you can use UML class diagram just explaining some concepts in any domain** [ not related to any software development activity]

[image]